# What Are the standards in mobile web application development?

Tags: security, jquery-mobile, mobile, web

I am working as a developer of a mobile team. Up to now, we have developed many navite mobile applications on windows mobile and android platforms. Our branch has groved up for the last 2 years and we have not many employees to work with. So we found a solution that covers platform-free application development. So, we will make it possible with a web based mobile application. WCF HTTP services, logging side, database, ssl certificate etc. are ready for this. My questions:

1. what are the **basics** of a mobile web application for security.
2. Is it possible to take mobile browser support that runs **HTML5** on any A-B-C generation mobile phones ?
3. jquery libraries for mobile (jquery mobile etc.) are secure enough for this?

Comment: 1. Basically the same as for other web applications. 2. Not sure what the question is. 3. Anything client side is never *secure*. 4. This is way too broad and ambiguous to be answered. If you have specific points that can be addressed, please ask about them individually. But "security basics" is a giant field which can hardly be distilled down into one answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you, or members of your team taken a look at the OWASP (Open-Web Application Security Project) wiki? They're an IT security interest group specializing in web application security, as well as general InfoSec (policy, programming, network authentication)

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets

They have provided a variety of FOSS resources for **fuzzing**, and additionally a variety of dense, no-fluff cheat sheets that I've found to be instrumental in my own pursuits. Good luck.

In particular:

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

If you're using an SQL back-end, be sure to sanitize your inputs and use prepared statements (friends don't let friends forget about SQLi)

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet